# Bootstrap isn't called into my Wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development

I keep getting an error when I look into my page resource about my bootstrap.min.css file, which gives me a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" => http://theasianbean.local/wp-content/themes/test-theme/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.map

However, bootstrap does show in the browser so it should be fine, right?
I am quite new to this and I don't understand why I get this error, yet my theme shows the bootstrap just fine.

I have this code:

```
function theme_add_bootstrap() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```

within my test-theme folder I have a folder named "bootstrap" in which I have my bootstraps CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 0):

**Put this code in `functions.php` file and check it.**

```
function theme_add_bootstrap() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_add_bootstrap' );
```